# Not able to connect to secure Kafka listener from java client api

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Getting this error while connecting to kafka on SSL:

**failed to find leader for Set([test,0])
kafka.common.BrokerEndPointNotAvailableException: End point with security protocol PLAINTEXT not found for broker 0**

listener and advised.listener is set to "10.0.1.3:9093"

can connect through terminal and send message but cannot connect from Java api .

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in error message 
Java client try to connect on plain protocol without SSL

Are you configure client according to docs
[Client configs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#security_configclients)

Comment: I am able to connect with PLAIN protocol as well with SSL config I can test with client terminal , issue occurs with JAVA api , yes my Client configs are like that only